# In an equation like i(t) = CdV/dt, is "V" the cause and "i" the effect?

Tags: basic, passive-components

In mechanics, almost all the time, force is the cause and acceleration the effect. If you apply a net force on an object, an acceleration can be observed. However this seems not that straightforward in electronics in relation to voltage and current.

I used to think that voltage is the cause and current is the effect. But then I came across solarcells, current sources etc and immediately realized my lack of imagination.

For each of the 3 passive components, is there a preference to think one quantity as cause and the other as effect or it is completely arbitrary?

```
Mechanics:  
If force is applied, velocity is changed .  
If velocity is changed(accelerating electrons), a force(emi) is produced.  

Resistor:  
If voltage is applied, current is produced.  
If current is applied, voltage is produced.

Capacitor:  
If current is applied, voltage is *changed*.  
If voltage is changed, a current is produced.  

Inductor:  
If voltage is applied, current is *changed*.  
If current is changed, voltage is produced.
```

Comment: V and I cannot happen independently of each other. Acceleration and force are the same but the difference is we can apply force with our hands so it is easy, and perhaps false, to think of force as the cause. We cannot do the same with neither voltage or current. Think of gravity...is it applying a force? Or a constant acceleration? That is not to say some approaches are more convenient than others depending on circumstance.

Comment: I feel gravitational force between two bodies is the cause and acceleration is the effect. I see your point though, general relativity breaks this kind of simplistic view... But still is there any advantage to think one as cause and the other as effect, especially for those  beginning to study electronics like me? @DKNguyen

Comment: "*is there any advantage to think one as cause and the other as effect*" Yes, but which is most convenient to use depends on circumstance.

Comment: In abstract, it's completely arbitrary so get used to thinking both ways instead of being set in one. In concrete, as @DKNguyen says, it depends on the example, and that's where ideal concepts like "voltage source" or "current source" come in (zero or infinite source impedance). Then you ask whether, in context, this battery is close to a voltage source, or this solar cell is better seen as a current source in parallel with a forward biased diode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not so simple even in mechanics. Imagine you are a nail, with a hammer coming fast towards you. In order to stop the hammer in the space available, it has to be accelerated (decelerated with a change of sign). While undergoing that rapid acceleration, it applies a large force to the nail.

The problem is what you mean by 'cause'.

Usually, we think of effect following cause, that cause never follows effect. The wayward football broke the neighbour's window. It is totally reasonable to argue that the broken window did not cause the football to be moving.

However, in electronics, and mechanics, where the behaviour of accelerations, forces, voltages and currents are conveniently described by equations of the form dI/dt = V/L, and f = ma, the two go hand in hand.

We can say the voltage across the coil caused the current to change, if that's convenient at the time, for instance when 'charging' the inductor of a boost DC-DC converter. We can also say that the changing current caused a large voltage across the coil, when 'discharging' the inductor of the same converter into the higher output voltage. Both descriptions are correct. It is not reasonable to argue that one did **not** cause the other. I've had long arguments about whether a BJT transistor is voltage controlled or current controlled. It is of course both, it's nonsense to argue that the current flow doesn't cause the voltage difference or *vice versa*, but concentrating on one or the other may be more useful choice at any given time.

Similarly, the large force applied to the hammer head by the nail caused it to slow down rapidly.

Answer (score 4):

Why not ask a similar question about a more basic equation, Ohm's law? If the voltage is equal to the current times the resistance, then which one produces the other... Voltage or Current?

The fact is that some equations do not imply cause on their own. They are simply *relations* between two things. Much like how 1 meter is 1000 millimeters, neither causes the other. They both exist within the same space and simply can be found via that relation.

It is natural for humans to think of force as a 'cause' because that's what we do... we exert forces on things. However, a force exerted on a mass (without other intervening forces) can be expressed as acceleration. It's simply a relation between a force and a mass.

Much in the same way, your question is a restatement of an old debate that does not really serve as more than philosophical discussion.

**Voltage** is a measurement of a difference in electrical potential between two points. It is defined as the amount of work per unit charge required to move a charge over a given distance.

**Current** is a measurement of the flow of charge within a given area. It is defined commonly as a flow of one Coloumb of charge per second.

Voltage can be measured without current (equipotential lines in a electric field, as an example) and current has been defined quite a few ways in the past without relation to voltage. Within the context of circuits, they are simply normally guaranteed *relations*, rather than causes and effect.

Even your equation above is a relation and has a form that expresses voltage across a capacitor with respect to the current.

$$v(t) = \frac{1}{C}\int_{t_0}^{t_1} i(t) dt +\ v(t_0)$$

Comment: If I understand correctly these guaranteed *relations* are *identities*  like \$(a+b)^2 = a^2+2ab+b^2\$ which can be viewed in either direction without any paradoxes. These are not one way logic statements like `if it rains, the road gets wet`.  Brilliantly explained! Thank you so much:)

Comment: equipotential lines in a *magnetic* field?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that the "cause and effect" consideration is particularly helpful. In fact many physical properties have "duality", i.e. they have "partners" that behave the same way if you swap the variables. For example capacitors and inductors are dual with respect to voltage and current. At the same time mass and springs are dual with respect to force and velocity.

It's actually quite helpful to analyze mechanical or acoustic systems using an electrical analogy and using electrical circuit analysis tools & methods. These are called Mechanical Electrical Analogies. It's actually straight forward to determine whether to equate Force with Current or Voltage. Hence two different analogies are used, depending on the problem. The "Mobility Analogy" (Force equivalent to current) and "Impedance Analogy" (Force equivalent to voltage).

The dual variable to Force is always Velocity (not acceleration or displacement). That's simply so that the product is the power. Voltage time current is power and so is Force times velocity. This way you get full symmetry in the physical laws.

$$F = m \cdot \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}, v = C \cdot \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$$

where F is force, v is velocity, m is mass and C is the compliance .

Good reading: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical%E2%80%93electrical_analogies

Comment: Wow I discovered a similar analogy like this on my own todayXD In an inductor, \$\text{v} = L\frac{di}{dt}\$ is dual of \$\text{velocity} = \dfrac{ds}{dt}\$. On solving both give the same expression for current/displacement: \$s(t) = s(0) + \int\limits_0^t v \, dt\$ I'm still going through the wiki. Thank you so much for introducing me to these:))